# Why I cannot store my image from the url in my folder?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I don't know what wrong why I cannot put the image in my folder?

Here's my php code:

```
    <?php
$img = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pg1dHauUL._SL75_.jpg';
$target_path = 'product-images/';
$target_path= $target_path.basename($img);

if(move_uploaded_file($img,$target_path)){
    echo 'Success';
}
else {
    echo 'Error.';
}

?>
```

Comment: You should have your client reconsider. There is no benefit to storing the image in a database. Operations on the table will be very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about fetching the image using `cURL` and then saving it to the database as a `BLOB`?

Comment: I thought blob was for binary data, isn't an image source text?

Comment: for example this is the image http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pg1dHauUL._SL75_.jpg

Comment: @Adam the OP stated that he can not store the path to the database. Then an image (the data) is binary, isn't it?? ;)

Comment: Yes it is, storing it on a blob column should fit what the OP needs. Upvoted.

Comment: I don't believe so. But it can be converted into binary for sure if it's not.

Comment: Images certainly aren't text; `BLOB` is the column type to use. Try opening an image in WordPad.

Comment: I opened a jpeg, it starts with 'JFIF'.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in your code, you're not actually getting the image. You can download the image source to your server in several ways.

```
$image = file_get_contents($URL);
```

or

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I believe that cURL is faster, if that matters. Then save the image source in a file,

```
file_put_contents( '/path/to/file/myimage.jpg', $image );
```

I hope that helps.